Connecting Emission to Material Output Volume Turns Object Black
I'm in the shader node editor, but as soon as I swap the Emission node connection from surface to volume in the material output, everything goes black.
I'm following a video tutorial, and the person in the video did not adjust any other settings as far as I'm aware. I didn't see any funny business happening with density or lighting or whatnot. The only difference I can visually see between our projects is that his noise texture node has an additional 'normalize' checkbox that mine simply doesn't have (the video is from March of this year).
Thanks for the help.





https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSjd6B0H_6Q&list=WL&index=10
I tried the principled volume node, but couldn't get a good effect (video moment is around min 10). I tried volume scatter and it had the exact same problem.

Oops Ok my bad, Emission should work, could you please share your file?



it's a curve object and it is made with geonodes so I'm a bit lost here, I hope someone will understand

It worked for me in 4.2.2. Maybe your version is too old?

Oh. That's actually a little embarrassing, I didn't realize I was still on 3.6... Thank you so much for posting, you saved me some heartache! This is my first post on this blender forum, do I need to resolve the thread somehow?

oh ok, great then, you can give the answer in the your Answer field   ;)
